# Delete specific whitespace backward with sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed, whitespace

Im trying to delete the last space in my string.

The input is:

```
"hi guys how you doing"
```

What i currently doing:

```
$ echo "hi guys how you doing" | sed 's/ \+//1'
```

Current output:

```
"higuys how you doing"
```

Expected output:

```
"hi guys how youdoing"
```

This string it's just for example, in my app i don't know the exact position of the whitespace, all I know is that it is in the last blank position.

Do you know if it exist any way to search backward the string without the rev command?

Comment: @MichaelO.: There's no `)` and I suggest to escape `(` and `)` with a backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's/\(.*[^[:space:]]\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}/\1/'
sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^[:space:]]*\)$/\1/'
```

If your `sed` supports `\s`, `\S` and if you prefer POSIX ERE, you may use

```
sed -E 's/(.*\S)\s+/\1/'
sed -E 's/\s+(\S*)$/\1/'
```

See the [`sed` demo](https://ideone.com/DEdQXi):

```
s="hi guys how you doing"
sed 's/\(.*[^[:space:]]\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}/\1/' <<< "$s"
# => hi guys how youdoing
```

**Details**

- `\(.*[^[:space:]]\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}` / `(.*\S)\s+` matches and captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars as many as possible up the last non-whitespace, and matches 1 or more whitespaces after it
- `[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^[:space:]]*\)$` / `\s+(\S*)$` matches 1+ whitespaces and then matches and captures into Group 1 zero or more non-whitespace chars  at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

this should work. it matches a single whitespace  followed by a sequence of non-whitespace characters at the end of the line `\([^ ]*\)$` and replaces it `\1` by the non-whitespace char sequence (hence dropping the matched whitespace char):

```
echo "hi guys how you doing" | sed 's/ \([^ ]*\)$/\1/g'
```

prints `hi guys how youdoing`

*update : changed the regex to only remove **the very last, single whitespace** character as suggested.*

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "hi guys how you doing" | sed 's/\(.*\) /\1/'
hi guys how youdoing
```

Comment: You will only remove 1 last space. It won't remove all of them if there are more than 1.

Comment: Right, it won't do anything other than exactly what the OP asked for and showed us in their sample input/output - "delete **the last space** in my string" (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 1):

With bash and a regex:

```
x="hi guys how you doing"
[[ "$x" =~ (.*)\ (.*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

Output:

```
hi guys how youdoing
```

Comment: If there are two spaces between `you` and `doing`, [one will remain](https://ideone.com/TkGxBY), only the last one will get removed.

Comment: That's all right. cport93 only wants to remove the last space.